# Details for proof of Poisson summation formula

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In the proof of the Poisson summation formula, there is a detail which is not clear to me how to resolve.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Schwartz-class function.

Let $F(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x-2\pi n)$. Why does the Fourier series of $F$ converge at any point $x$, i.e. $$F(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{F}(k)e^{ikx}?$$

Comment: $F$ is an infinitely differentiable periodic function, so the Fourier series converges everywhere (and to $F$). This is a very standard fact about Fourier series.

Comment: @Potato I agree that's a standard fact. But how do we prove that $F$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is a Schwartz function, by definition we have that there exists $C>0$ such that $(2\pi+|x|)^2|f(x)|\leq C$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, for $x\in [0,2\pi]$, we have

$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |f(x-2\pi n)| \leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{C}{(2\pi +|x-2\pi n|)^2} \leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{C}{(2\pi -|x| +2\pi |n|)^2} \leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{C}{(2\pi |n|)^2}.
$$

This implies, by Weierstrass' M-test that the sum defining $F$ is absolutely and uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ (by periodicity). Since $f'$ is a Schwartz function whenever $f$ is, we can apply the same argument above to the (in principle formal) derivatives of $F$, given by the sum of the  derivatives of the $f(x-2\pi n)$, to conclude that $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Now it's just a matter of integrating by parts to conclude since $\widehat{F^{(m)}}(k)=(ik)^m\hat{F}(k)$, so that, again by Weierstrass, the Fourier series of $F$ converges uniformly in $[0,2\pi]$ to $F$.

Comment: I agree up to that the sum defining $F$ is absolutely and uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, how do you know that the derivatives of $F$ are given by the sum of the derivatives of the $f(x-2\pi n)$?

Comment: If you have a series of $C^1$ functions $\sum f_n$ such that it, along with the series of derivatives, converge uniformly then the series is $C^1$ with the derivative given by the series of derivatives.

Comment: Hmm.. I've never heard that result. Does it have a name, or is it easy to prove?

Comment: Prove it for sequences: Assume $f_n\to f$ and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly. Then $$f_n(x)-f_n(y)=\int_x^y f_n'(t)dt.$$ Take the limit on both sides and conclude.